# for a static member initialization outside its class declaration, is it necessary to provide its type?

Tags: c++, class, oop, static

I have a class in

Game.h:

```
class Game 
{
public:

    ~Game (){}

    bool init(const char* title,int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height,bool fullscreen );


    void render();
    void update() ;
    void handleEvents();
    void clean();
    void draw();
    static Game* Instance();
    // a function to acces the private running variable 
    bool running () {return m_bRunning; }

private:
    Game ();
    static Game* s_pInstance;
    SDL_Window* m_pWindow;
    SDL_Renderer* m_pRenderer;
    bool m_bRunning;
    int m_currentFrame;

};

//create the typedef
typedef Game TheGame;
```

and also in Game.cpp I have a static variable initialization like the following

```
Game* Game::s_pInstance = 0;
```

**So I intend to know why I need to use (`Game*`) variable type in here and is it a must?**

Comment: Yes.  Also the typedef is not required - it serves no purpose.

Comment: Unrelated: You may find the [Meyers Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/4581301) a bit more convenient (and as of C++ 11 safer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a static variable initialization like the following
>
> ```
> Game* Game::s_pInstance = 0;
> ```

This description is incomplete. More accurate: you have a static variable **definition**, and an initialization is part of this definition. The initialization does not need to mention the type, but the definition does. Syntactically, you could leave off the initialization part (drop `= 0`), but you would still need the definition in order to use the variable. *Caveat: don't really drop the initialization except as an experiment to see that this compiles.*

The definition needs to include the type of the thing being defined. That's the way the language works. On a more technical level, the presence of the type probably helps identify the line as a definition instead of an expression.

Comment: So you are saying I don't need to explicitly use Game* for the initialization part but it would be a good practice to add that as it makes the code lot clearer to understand

Comment: @rudrasarkar No you misunderstood. `Game*` is required here. `Game*` is part of the definition, the initialisation is `= 0`.

Comment: @rudrasarkar As well as answering your question JaMiT was correcting your terminology. As stated what you have there is fundamentally a definition, and a definition requires a type.